# Color Indicator for Code Changes – Track Changes in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 SDK to change the behavior of the Track Changes?

I would like to override it to add some other capabilities, but didn't found the way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to create a margin provider that either occupies the same space or is adjacent to the track changes margin.

In general, to create a margin in the editor, you'll want to export a `IWpfTextViewMarginProvider` class.  Next, you need to position the margin
using [PredefinedMarginNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.predefinedmarginnames.aspx).

Here is an example that should get you started:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61915/Numbered-Bookmarks-Visual-Studio-Extension-VSX-201

Comment: Thanks gameweld. I know about adding a new margin, but I especially wanted to change the behavior of the Track Changes. But I guess I will end up having to have an adjacent margin